# Hard drive shows as "uninitialized" in my NAS (Linux) but is fine in Windows7

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, nas

My NAS (QNAP) has had issues with seeing / not seeing 2nd disk of the RAID which I have located to a dodgy SATA cable. I have replaced the cable and the disk appears to be fine and recognized etc but shows as "uninitialized".
I am not able to manage / format it from within the NAS but plugging it into my external dock I can see and format and chkdisk it in Windows 7. All is fine but when I insert it back into the NAS it is still showing up as uninitialized. I am not concerned about any data on it as I will rebuild the Raid array and restore.
I don't have a Linux box to run it in for fdisk etc.
(The NAS file system is ext4)

Any ideas or helpful suggestions?

Thanks - Mark

Comment: Did you try googling ?  There are many answers such as https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/knowledge-base/article/the-different-ways-of-resetting-your-nas-explained

Comment: I have not found any helpful info about this specific problem. I have swapped the hard drives etc but the problem appears to be with this specific drive, possibly the way it is formatted etc. It is fine in W7 but the NAS just will not allow me to do anything with it.  It does recognise it and the SMART will do a full check and display all info etc.  My Qnap is an older version and the manuals do not have any info regarding this particular problem other than the system will recognise and if necessary format it to ext4 which it is not doing.

Answer (score 0):

What RAID?

I wouldn't trust any windows tools to make/handle any non-native filesystems.
And I strongly doubt windows can "chkdisk" ext4.

You can live-boot almost any flavour of linux you like, to throw some useful/ apropriate tools at the disk/NAS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Raid1 - that is on and done by the NAS itself which is some or other flavour of Linux. Only trying to format / initialize the drive on Windows machine but it still does not work on the NAS which is supposed to auto initialze and format any new disk....

Comment: WAG but windows will be adding MBR/GPT which the NAS may flag and refuse to overwrite. The NAS comes with some kind of interface? And there's no option to force an initialisation? Quickly checked/solved with *nux live environment, or find a friend with one.

Comment: I ended up running clean/all with diskpart and it fixed the issue. When I installed the disk the NAS now happily accepted and formatted it correctly.